# How to recreate nginix.pid when I deleted it from tmp folder?

Tags: nginx, server

So I tried to free up some space in nginx server and I deleted content of tmp files.

Then When i tried to run command:

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I got error:

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2018/04/27 10:33:44 [emerg] 1580#1580: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Is there anyway to recreate nginx.pid file?. I also created manually nginx/error.log file and gave them permissions `chmod -R 777`.

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /var/log/nginx` then restart nginx again,  nginx.pid file automatically iss created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)) the files and then start again nginx, for example:

```
# touch /var/log/nginx/error.log
# touch /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Test if your config just to verify and start again, the pid will be automatically created:

```
# nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

From the [command line](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/) example from the docs you could also do:

```
nginx -t -c /path/to/nginx.conf -g "pid /var/run/nginx.pid; worker_processes 2;"
```